# Integral of $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{a+bx^{2\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)}-x^2}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

Can you do
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{a+bx^{2\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)}-x^2}}$$
with $a,b\geq0$ and $k$ is a integer bigger than $1$. Can it be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals? Most of the examples I tried to put in WolframAlpha gave results in terms of elliptic integrals. Any answer in terms on special functions implementable on Mathematica would be nice.

Comment: Also, can someone explain why anyone would downvote the question?

Comment: I returned the vote, but your question is really off-topic, and you should add your efforts to help people solving it!

Comment: I actually don't know anything about elleptic integrals. Ran into this while doing a physics problem. Can you tell me what I should add?

Comment: Your integral has some parameters, this makes it hard, is it possible to restrict them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80385/discussion-between-chetan-vuppulury-and-user-108128).

Comment: Hey, I've removed a parameter and put two constraints on a,b. Is it possible now?

Comment: if $a=0$ then Yes, is possible Now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{a+bx^{2\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)}-x^2}}=\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{a+x^2\left(bx^{-\frac{1}{k}}-1\right)}}$

Let $u=x^{-\frac{1}{k}}$ ,

Then $x=u^{-k}$

$dx=-ku^{1-k}~du$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{a+x^2\left(bx^{-\frac{1}{k}}-1\right)}}=-k\int\dfrac{u^{1-k}}{\sqrt{a+u^{-2k}\left(bu-1\right)}}~du$

Comment: And this is better because?